# Iterating over a Vec<Vec<T>> struct

Tags: rust

With the below code snippet, Rustc gives the error `cannot index into a value of type Matrix<T>`.

What would be the proper way to access the vectors inside the Matrix struct in such cases?

```
pub struct Matrix<T>(pub Vec<Vec<T>>);

impl<T> Add for Matrix<T> {

    fn add(self, other_matrix: Self) -> Option<Self> {

        let mut vector_1 = vec![];

        for x in 0..self.len() {
            for y in 0..self[x].len() {
                let total = self[x][y] + other_matrix[x][y];
                vector_1.push(total);
            }
            // ... //
        }
    }

}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please check the code in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73695641/iterating-over-a-vecvect-struct/73695741?noredirect=1#comment130189621_73695741), it might provide you the abstraction you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `identifier.order` syntax to access a member of a tuple struct. In your case, it becomes `self.0`, and your snippet becomes like this:

```rust
for x in 0..self.0.len() {
  for y in 0..self.0[x].len() {
    let total = self.0[x][y] + other_matrix.0[x][y];
    vector_1.push(total);
  }
...
```

Comment: This can be improved via extending Matrix type as Indexable, without exposing the inner field: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=179b30a9c99f79830181b337c39e164f

Comment: @ÖmerErden That's even a better suggestion. I just wanted to address how to access tuple struct members.

Comment: Question is closed via dupe hammer so I decided to attach the alternative one here ^^ but this post is the actual solution, it is much more instructive for new starters or confused ones, that's what I did under the hood as well

Comment: Thanks for the additional input @ÖmerErden! 